# writing dbms_output for excel

Tags: database, excel

Help me to solve this

when i write the dbms_output.put_line for printing data in sql developer 
iam getting the data the contious form to change that iam using (spaces or pipe) symbol. But my problem is that copying the data to excel sheet.

if i need to copy to excel then iam writing in this format 
dbms_output.put_line(hello||','||world)

and then pasting the data in excel and using the options in excel as

data --> text to columns --> delimiter --> by clicking on comma then the data gets seperated

But i need a way to write dbms_output.put_line in such a way so that i can directly copy my data and paste it in excel .

Thanks for the great help

Answer (score 0):

Write a file with a `.csv` suffix and open this with excel.

Better than using `dbms_output` might be to use `utl_file`.

Comment: can u please share a small example it will be more help ful to me